# How to add entity framework 6 provider in code?

Tags: c#, connection-string, entity-framework-6

I use Entity Framework 6 in a C# application and it works perfectly. When creating the Model, the app.config is generated with all the necessary configuration. Now I don't like having stuff in the app.config, so I use the connection string builder. I succeeded in removing everything out of the app.config file except of this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

If I remove this, it does not work. So how can I translate that config into c# code?
How to I do that? I've looked at the code-based configuration (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699) however, it did not help.

My partial class that creates the connection string looks like that:

```
public partial class LogEntities
    {
        public LogEntities(string serverName)
            : base(GetConnectionString(serverName))
        {
        }

        public static string GetConnectionString(string serverName)
        {
            // Specify the provider name, server and database.
            const string databaseName = "_LOG";

            // Initialize the connection string builder for the underlying provider.
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = serverName,
                InitialCatalog = databaseName,
                IntegratedSecurity = true,
                MultipleActiveResultSets = true
            };

            // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
            System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

            // Set the provider-specific connection string.
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/myproject.LogModel.csdl|res://*/myproject.LogModel.ssdl|res://*/myproject.LogModel.msl";

            return entityBuilder.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The answer is in the link you provided

Answer (score 15):

In EF6 you can use Code Base configuration. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx) article for more details. It shows how to set the default connection factory (use the `SetDefaultConnectionFactory` method). To set the provider you use the `SetProviderServices` method.

Comment: You linked him to an article on msdn that he already mentioned. Also that article does not tell you how to make sql connections strings.

Comment: @Bob - I don't know if I missed the link or the question was updated with the link after I added the answer. The interesting thing is that the article I pointed to actually contains a snippet showing how to set the default connection factory. Anyways, I improved the answer a little bit and gave some pointers that should make it easy to work things out.

Comment: @Pawel +1 Your answer is correct, the code is halfway down the link you provided and would in fact allow his App.config to be free of the <entityFramework element at the bottom, just as he requested. Helped me out, many thanks.